# Multivalued form field and validation for empty values

Tags: forms, validation, empty

I am designing a dynamic form with multivalued field (with the famous "Add another value" button).

My question concerns the validation of this type of fields :

Should blank values be blocking (the user has to remove empty input fields before submitting the form) or should the form take care of removing those empty fields at submit ?

Update : mockup added as requested

[image]

Comment: Have you got a mockup of your current form - or at least of these type of fields?

Comment: doesn't that depend on the _type_ of the field? if the content can be edited later, leaving it empty might be fine. "hours worked" will be empty in the beginning, but a user might want to enter a value without adding the whole field.

Comment: As it is a dynamically generated form, there is no way to specialize according the semantic of the fields.

Comment: I see. I thought it would be more like defining a template for later re-use.

Comment: What is the user describing?

Comment: The user is describing a content for which he has previously specified the attributes list with different properties (such as multivalued), so, as I said, there is no way to specialize according the semantic of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this implemented in one of my recent projects where we had to use a multivalue form to add user names to the list. If an user tried to add a new field and there was an empty field already available, we showed **an error message which asked users to populate the previously added new field before adding a new one and also disabled the add button**.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyymEQ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However if the user did delete the empty field then the button was re-enabled.

We found this to be really useful as **we often found users had added a new field to add a specific value and got distracted and forgotten to add it** and the alert allowed them to check the data again

Comment: This is the solution I wanted to implement in the first place, but I was not sure than blocking the user was the right solution...